# Any way of capturing the users response like accept/reject to a calendar invitation?

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-cloud-platform, google-calendar-api, google-api-nodejs-client

I was trying to insert a calendar and add an attendee, it is working fine. But my problem is understanding how can I listen to the attendee's responses to the inserted calendar, is there any way or suggestion, will be a help.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/v3/reference/events/watch